# GAE's webapp2_extra.i18n can't import babel on MacOSX

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I followed the tutorial to enable i18n functionality in my GAE project:

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/i18n.html

However, after I easy_install the babel, I can't access my GAE due to the error:

```
File "/Users/myname/Developer/GAE/project/webapp2_extras/i18n.py", line 16, in <module>
    import babel
ImportError: No module named babel
```

And I tried to load it in my cmdline:

```
 $ python2.7
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import babel
>>>
```

It works fine!

I suspect the problem is that GAE can't load the library, but I don't know how to solve it.

Please help, thanks!

My working environment is MaxOSX Lion, Python2.7, GAE 1.6.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [doc](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/i18n.html) states

> For App Engine, download babel and pytz and add those libraries to
>   your app directory.

That means you have to copy them into the app directory, not easy_install, as the SDK has import restrictions to emulate the production environment.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the saying "App Engine users also need babel installed, as we use the command line utility provided py it to extract and update message catalogs." in the document. The only thing I need to do is to copy the lib to my project directory! The reason we need to install (for app engine) is only to compile the language data. Thanks!

Comment: Just don't use the official pytz. A much lighter (equivalent) package is http://code.google.com/p/gae-pytz/

Comment: I easy_installed babel and then symlinked: `ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Babel-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/babel babel`. Worked great!