# Setting up i18n with python GAE: importError No module named babel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

[GAE's webapp2_extra.i18n can't import babel on MacOSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898491/gaes-webapp2-extra-i18n-cant-import-babel-on-macosx)
I followed the post above and added babel and pytz libraries under the file path /lib.

But when I call `from webapp2_extras import i18n`, I still get `ImportError: No module named babel`

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: What is the name of the .py file?

Comment: /controllers/Handler.py.

Comment: is ~$projectdir/lib/` in $PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score -1):

Include those lib into your project, ideal is to make a symlik

Comment: Can you add more details to you answer?